# Knockout js observe div value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

My question start from early question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897411/knockout-js-observable-array-data-group-total-age-count-per-section)

In this age is a slider from 1 to 20 (please consider this for example). Now I am storing at that value of the slider in another div (this one holds the actual age). I am writing an change event for the div or input(hidden) (since there is no change event for these) so I want to build a custom one when the text changes in the div I want the event to fire.

Some code:

```
<div class="readonly" data-bind="text: Points, event:{customevent :$.root.value_changed}"></div>
<input class="points" type="hidden" data-bind="text: Points, event:{customevent :$.root.value_changed}" />
```

JavaScript

```
customViewModel : function() {

  var self = this;
  self.value_changed = function (data) {
  };

},
```

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger this event on the element:

```
$("div").trigger("customevent");​
```

Working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qU7c8/1/